# ORACLE SQL compare two or more rows in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with values similar to this

```
Uname | Grp_ID | Role_ID
---------------------
usr1  | 10     | 1032
usr1  | 10     | 1034
usr1  | 20     | 1032
usr1  | 20     | 1034
usr1  | 30     | 1032
usr1  | 40     | 1032
usr1  | 50     | 1034
usr1  | 50     | 1034
usr1  | 60     | 1018
usr1  | 70     | 1057
```

I want output Grp_IDs which have 1032 and 1034 (both) as the Role_IDs
For example,

```
Grp_ID 10 has 1032 and 1034 as ROle_IDs
Grp_ID 20 has 1032 and 1034 as ROle_IDs
```

Grp_ID 30, 40, 50, 60 ,70 do not have both 1032 and 1034 as Role_IDs

I have tried used inner joins and 'having' but don't seem to get what I want.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your data table... I see group 20 having both 1032 and 1034...

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY having count distinct.

Comment: Sorry. I added Grp_ID 20 by mistake. I have edited my question now. Please check.

Comment: If a grp_ID existed having roles of 1032, 1034 and 1057 would you want that one as well?  The statement you made, "I want output Grp_IDs which have 1032 and 1034 (both) as the Role_IDs For example," seems to indicate yes, unless you excluded the word only.

Answer (score 2):

I like to approach these problems using `group by` and `having`.  In this case:

```
select grp_id
from tbl 
where role_id in (1032, 1034)
group by grp_id 
having count(distinct role_id) = 2;
```

I find that this method generalizes to many variations of set-within-sets questions.

Comment: Yeah that looks way nicer and the explain plan (on mini data, but still) is cheaper than a self join.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select t1.uname, t2.grp_id, t1.role_id from table_name t1 
left join table_name t2 on t1.grp_is = t2.grp_id
Where t1.role_id = 1032 and t2.role_id = 1034
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is join the table to itself on group id, and then filter for rows that contain both of your role ids. Each table involved in the join contributes a different role. If you needed to filter on 3 values, then you'd need 3 table clauses (two joins).

```
WITH thetable AS (
  SELECT 10 grpid, 1032 roleid FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 grpid, 1034 roleid FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 20 grpid, 1032 roleid FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 20 grpid, 1034 roleid FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 30 grpid, 1032 roleid FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 40 grpid, 1032 roleid FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 50 grpid, 1034 roleid FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 50 grpid, 1034 roleid FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 60 grpid, 1018 roleid FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 70 grpid, 1057 roleid FROM dual
)
SELECT t1.grpid, t1.roleid, t2.roleid
FROM thetable t1
JOIN thetable t2 ON t1.grpid = t2.grpid
WHERE t1.roleid = 1032 AND t2.roleid = 1034;


groupid  roleid  roleid_1
10       1032    1034
20       1032    1034
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer a different answer:

```
SELECT GrpID FROM theTable WHERE roleId = 1032
INTERSECT
SELECT GrpID FROM theTable WHERE roleID = 1034
```

or

```
SELECT 'Grp_ID '|| GRPID ||' has 1032 and 1034 as Role_IDs' 
FROM theTable 
WHERE roleId = 1032
INTERSECT
SELECT 'Grp_ID '|| GRPID ||' has 1032 and 1034 as Role_IDs' 
FROM theTable 
WHERE roleID = 1034
```

if you need the full text as in your question...

but I'm not a big fan of adding text like this in the SQL presentation layer should take care of it.

Comment: Group by (as shown in other answers) scans the table only once, instead of twice as any INTERSECT solution would do. Those solutions are likely to be quite a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As @jarlh told, this would do. Here I am not using filter on `uname`

```
with tbl (Uname,Grp_ID,Role_ID) as 
(   select 'usr1',10,1032 from dual union all
    select 'usr1',10,1034 from dual union all
    select 'usr1',20,1032 from dual union all
    select 'usr1',20,1034 from dual union all
    select 'usr1',30,1032 from dual union all
    select 'usr1',40,1032 from dual union all
    select 'usr1',50,1034 from dual union all
    select 'usr1',50,1034 from dual union all
    select 'usr1',60,1018 from dual union all
    select 'usr1',70,1057 from dual
)
--Query
select grp_id
 ,count(distinct role_id) as count_dist_role_id 
from tbl 
where Role_ID in (1032,1034)
group by grp_id 
having count(distinct role_id)=2
```

Output

```
+--------+--------------------+
| GRP_ID | COUNT_DIST_ROLE_ID |
+--------+--------------------+
|     20 |                  2 |
|     10 |                  2 |
+--------+--------------------+
```

Comment: @YasarAbdullah - two things: First, the solution based on "group by" as shown by Ustav (and by Gordon in another answer) is likely to be much faster than solutions using JOIN of any kind. And, as Ustav said, his solution does not match rows by `uname` - you need to clarify what your requirement really is. If the same GRP_ID has both 1032 and 1034, but for different `uname`, is that still OK, or should the grouping be by `uname` also?